# Binding jQuery to Dynamic HTML without User Interaction

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, binding

I am working with the `on()` method and am successfully binding some jQuery to HTML elements that are dynamically added to the page:

```
$('#video').on('click', 'a.expand', function() {
  // Do something
});
```

In this case, a div with id "video" is dynamically added to the page.  Inside that div, there is an anchor to toggle the visibility of said div.  It works great by clicking said anchor, but what I am trying to find out is what event can I list instead of "click" to bind my jQuery to that div WHEN it is added to the page, NOT when you interact with it?

I have looked all over and have only seen talk of "click", "focus", etc but not a way to do this without some kind of interaction.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to execute the function upon inserting of that `div`?

Comment: Yes.  I figured replacing "click" with something else would do that, but I cannot find what that would be.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the function upon inserting of that `div`, then you need to find the event handler, which inserts the `div` and then in the end, you need to call the function.

```
function (){
    $("body").append("#video");
    // Call your function after this append() function is done.
    myEventFunction();
}
```

If you know the cases, where the `div` is inserted, this is the best method.

Comment: Thank you.  That's another good approach, but if I don't know the cases where the `div` is inserted, and want to bind the function as declared originally, _when_ the `div` is inserted, there is not a way to do that?

Comment: Gimme some time. Will try to find and update them in the answer. `:)`